# Force non-interactive "dpkg --configure" when using apt-get install

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am installing packages on remote server, using `ssh`:

```
ssh root@my-host "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true apt-get --quiet --yes install w3m"
```

even though I have set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, the installation gets stuck on following question, and I have to press enter manually:

```
Configuration file '/etc/w3m/config'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** config (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I suspect, the question is being asked by `dpkg --configure -a` and not by `apt-get` and therefore noninteractive is ignored.

**How can I automate this and have default option selected automatically, without being asked ?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This kind of configuration file change conflict is dealt with by `dpkg`, and you can force it to choose the default option using the `--force-confdef` option. Do heed the warning from [the documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg.1) though:

> Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts only. Using them without fully  understanding  their
> effects may break your whole system.

To provide this option when `dpkg` is invoked by APT, you need to add it to the APT settings, for example by adding the following line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
DPkg::options { "--force-confdef"; };
```

or, for a single invocation:

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef ...
```

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` only affects `debconf`, and that’s not involved at all in this scenario.