# apt-get -y upgrade keep asking me to confirm keep /tmp/grub.xC3mMKP0zx file and i can't skip it

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

We have automated build bash script
where at the beginning executed command

```
apt-get update;
apt-get upgrade -q -y -u 
  --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages 
  --allow-change-held-packages --allow-unauthenticated;
```

but it keeps asking this question with popup in terminal

> A new version (/tmp/grub.xC3mMKP0zx) of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.

[image]

which is reason that automated script execution is hanging and i can't force skip it somehow with --allow* or -y options

our ubuntu is **16.04**

**how i kan avoid that popup appearce ?**

Please help, Thanks

**-- UPDATE --**

I have tried many solutions 
**also this one:** [Force non-interactive "dpkg --configure" when using apt-get install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416815/force-non-interactive-dpkg-configure-when-using-apt-get-install) which was mentioned as duplicate to this question

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef upgrade -q -y -u --force-yes
```

it still the same promt popup asking for choose default option

Comment: Any comment why -1 ?

Comment: @StephenKitt actually this is not duplicate in your suggested article it is suggested to pass none interactive option it is done here -y param is passed. The problem is that popup is not yes/no question but choose option

Comment: The problem you’re running into is the same: installing a package stops because of a file conflict during the installation. The answer explains how to resolve the file conflict without manual intervention.

Comment: @StephenKitt actually solution suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416815/force-non-interactive-dpkg-configure-when-using-apt-get-install not works for me. `apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef upgrade -q -y -u --force-yes` anyway **keep promoting** with option popup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found **DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive** option here: https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install

And only combination of DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive and Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" prevented that **option popup** to open

So the final command is

```
apt-get update;
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -q -y -u  -o 
   Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" --allow-downgrades 
   --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages 
   --allow-change-held-packages --allow-unauthenticated;
```