# Is DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive redundant with apt-get -yqq?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm a noob in both Docker and Linux and studying a Dockerfile from a shared project I work on. Something I don't understand-- at the top of the Dockerfile we have:

```
# Never prompts the user for choices on installation/configuration of packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

But then in a whole series of later Docker `RUN` commands, I see that `-yqq` is appended to all the `apt-get` commands: `apt-get {install,update,upgrade} -yqq ...`. Since `-yqq` is supposed to automatically answer questions for `apt-get` and make it silent, I'm confused as to whether it's redundant. But I'm having a hard time finding straightforward answers, so here are some questions:

- Does `apt-get` directly read the value of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` and set options accordingly?
- Are `-y` and `-qq` redundant for one or more of `apt-get {install,update,upgrade}` if `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND` is read by `debconf`, which is used to prompt for input in many packages’ maintainer scripts. `apt` does *not* take this environment variable into account, so `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is *not* redundant with `apt`’s `-y` and `-q` options.

Various other tools can be involved in package installations; see for example [Force non-interactive "dpkg --configure" when using apt-get install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416815/86440).